# How to exclude "?" for Null value from DB2 Select

Tags: sql, db2

I am extracting data from DB2 to Dataset via submitting the job(JCL) using **DSNTIAUL**. Some of column having null value but after extraction in dataset null value are placed like "?" For example: 
Table1:

[image: the table structure]

Select Query :

```
Select Column1,column2,Cloumn3
from Table1;
```

Output Dataset :

```
AAAAA......................?.......BBBBBB
CCCCC......DDDDDD.......................?
```

Could someone help to exclude "?" from the dataset. I tried with COALESCE but no luck. or should i need to write separate SORT step in JCL  to remove "?".

And also is there any possible way extract data into CSV format

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
select column1, coalesce(nullif(column2, '?'), nullif(column3, '?'))
```

If both columns have `'?'`s, then this will return `NULL`.

Comment: Thanks,  i will try that

Comment: Is there any possible way to extract in CSV format instead of giving : SELECT column1,',',column2 .........       or using ||','|| ?

Comment: @ASV.AadhithyaAadhithya . . . I don't understand your last comment.  Please ask new questions as a *question* rather than in a comment.